# Plotting matplotlib errorbars gives AssertionError assert vertices.ndim == 2

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two *100x1* arrays which I am plotting against each other. I can plot them easily enough and obtain the expected result however, when I try to add any kind of error bars to the plot I get the error message

```
    User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 147, in__init__
   assert vertices.ndim == 2
   AssertionError
```

My basic code is just:

```
    xe = numpy.ones((100,1))
    pyplot.figure()
    pyplot.scatter(frac_K,frac_en)
    pyplot.errorbar(frac_K,frac_en, xerr = xe, yerr =xe, linestyle = 'none')

    pyplot.show()
```

*frac_K* and *frac_en* are defined earlier in the script as simply *100x1* arrays. i.e.

```
    print frac_K
    [[-0.        ]
    [-0.00180161]
    [-0.00452353]
    [-0.00815248]
    [-0.01267089]
    ... etc.
```

Any guidance on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `numpy.ones((100,1))` you are creating a 2D array (one with the dimensions 100 x 1). You can either call call `.flatten()` on `xe` to turn it into a 1D array, or create it as 1D.

```
xe = numpy.ones((100,1)).flatten()
```

or...

```
xe = numpy.ones(100)
```

This is actually exactly what `assert vertices.ndim == 2` is telling you, albeit in a slightly cryptic way. e.g.

```
>>> xe = numpy.ones((100,1))
>>> xe.ndim
2

>>> xe = numpy.ones(100)
>>> xe.ndim
1
```

The property `ndim` is short for "number of dimensions".